# Interpreting Windows CHKDSK unspecified error codes

Tags: chkdsk

I ran `chkdsk` on my PC. During Stage 4, after it finished looking for bad clusters in user file data, it immediately printed out:

```
An unspecified error occurred (766f6c756d652e63 470).
```

then exited.

I can't find any documentation on the error codes printed. I've seen both `766f6c756d652e63` and `470` on forums, but no interpretation or info on what the codes mean and why `chkdsk` printed them. Currently, I can't judge the severity of `chkdsk` crashing during Stage 4, and I don't know why it failed.

I'm interested in knowing what the two error codes (`766f6c756d652e63` and `470`) mean, both specifically in this output and in general. If there's an online resource documenting them, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what practical problem decyphering the fail code would solve. Format it, test it again. Have a look at the SMART data. Decide whether you might trust it a while longer or just bin it now.

Comment: @Tetsujin Can you please share why you can't see a practical reason for deciphering the fail codes? I imagine knowing why it failed would help one either prevent it from failing upon reinvocation, or, if the failure is due to a problem with the drive itself, could give an idea of how bad the condition of the drive is. Are none of these reasonable? At the very least, you seem to know enough about the error codes to know if there's no practical use for them; I'd appreciate it if you could enlighten me on that point, since I can't find any info on them anywhere.

Comment: I query your need to know, so you query my need to know why you need to know. As a debating  strategy… meh. Sometimes, people ask leading questions, intended to lead the student towards working something out for themself. Anyway… knowing the answer to your question will not get you one iota closer to a solution to your actual problem. You just seemed to think it would. I was more practically pointing towards something that might help; or when to perhapss consider the drive to be no longer worth the effort.

Comment: @Tetsujin I figured that might be the case. The SMART data led me in the right direction for checking the state of my disk. Nevertheless, the reason I actually asked this question was more so for interest; I actually tried to leave out as many details of my actual issue, (if it could even be called one), as possible. (The drive which this error was raised on is actually working perfectly fine, but I wanted to know what information one could garner off the error if any, in general.)

Comment: As it turns out, the error codes don't give me useful info about my disk, but knowing that the codes aren't useful is better for me now than seeing it on forum posts and wondering if it contains the answer. I didn't mean to argue. I hope that clarifies why I asked the question initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So these appear to be a very internal windows errors if we convert the first part

> 766f6c756d652e63

to ASCII it gives us the value

> volume.c

This could either be referring to a file in the windows source code, or it could be referring to an error on your C drive.

The number could be a line number in that source code file or an internal error code. Either way, Microsoft does not publish any information I can see online about this. So sadly, other than decoding the first part, that is as far as we can get without source code access or some low-level reverse engineering.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the error codes don't seem to give much more information than this, but it's nice to know more about them, even if that means finding out they aren't that useful for my disk issue. Thanks a bunch, especially for the fast response!

Comment: I did find various results on google for users with this error; however, nothing relating to the exact meaning of the error, more so just generic troubleshooting of disk issues. If you have a more general disk problem, post it as a new question, and maybe we can help with that directly.

Comment: file ID perhaps